# Gatsby GraphyQL File Returns Wrong Image

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

So I am trying to get the image that is defined in my markdown post and when I use GraphQLi, the query works, but in my JS code its returning the wrong image.

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import { GatsbyImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

export const Img = (props: { alt: string; src: string }): ReactElement => {
  const { alt, src } = props;

  const imageName = src.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query GetImage($imageName: String) {
      file(relativePath: { eq: $imageName }) {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  console.log(imageName, data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData);

  return <GatsbyImage alt={alt} image={data.file.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} />;
};
```

The results of the console log

[image: Results of console log]

I would expect the office1 image but its returning me the docker image

UPDATE 1:

So I am trying out StaticImage as it seems that the use query is not expecting variables. So I have the following code that still does not render the image at all, not even the alt text

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

export const Img = (props: { alt: string; src: string }): ReactElement => {
  const { alt, src } = props,
    imageUrl = `../../images/${src}`;

  console.log(imageUrl);
  console.log('----');

  return <StaticImage alt={alt} src={imageUrl} />;
};
```

Image url logs `../../images/office1.jpg`. If I do the following the image renders fine

```
return <StaticImage alt={alt} src='../../images/office1.jpg' />;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you spot all the issues:

1. `StaticQuery` (or `useStaticQuery`) doesn't accept variables (hence the name) so the following snippet will never work:

   ```
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query GetImage($imageName: String) {
        file(relativePath: { eq: $imageName }) {
          childImageSharp {
           gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    `);
   ```

   From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/#known-limitations):

   > `useStaticQuery` does not accept variables (hence the name “static”),
   > but can be used in any component, including pages
2. `StaticImage` doesn't accept dynamic parameters, it's a [known restriction](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage):

   > The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
   > restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
   > to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
   > them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
   > function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
   > variables within the component’s local scope

   So this means that you can't lift or pass any value from props but you can get static/local access to the route:

   This will work:

   ```
    export function Image() {
      const source= 'image.png'; 
       return <StaticImage src={source} />
    }
   ```

   This won't:

   ```
    export function Image(props) {
       return <StaticImage src={props.source} />
    }
   ```

Both are known restrictions well documented

So, answering your question, you have 2 options (at least) if you want to use dynamic sources:

- Use standard `<img>` tag with a dynamic source
- Use `GatsbyImage` along with JavaScript filtering ([`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), etc) using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) (not static). Another restriction of page queries is that they only work in top-level components (pages) so the idea is to place there your query and drill drown the images to the component to filter them if needed using JavaScript in the same way that you did with `$imageName`.

Comment: I am not sure I am following what you are suggestion the solution is @ferran-buireu

Comment: My suggestions are: 1) use a regular `<img>` tag. 2) Use a page query instead of a static query (because of the limitation). There, you can query all the images and filter them using any JS loop along with a `GatsbyImage` (because of the `StaticImage` limitation)

Comment: Ok, yeah, makes sense. got it to work that way